# Why isn't try/catch Exceptions working for Gson.fromJson()?

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, gson

I've been getting com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException from calling Gson.fromJson(), so added a catch(Exception) logic, but the error is never getting caught and just getting thrown!

Here's what I have:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(getOrderUrlWithId)
            .get()
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = this.okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        GetOrderResult orderResult = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(response.body().string()), GetOrderResult.class);
        response.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error retrieving order : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error happening for client PO: " + clientPO, e);
        return null;
    }
```

When I run the test I get "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
"

Why isn't the error getting caught?

Here's the Stack trace:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
at com.hub.fulfill.circlegraphics.getOrdersByCgOrderId(CircleGraphicsApi.java:164)
```

Comment: it is because "test" is not valid json in string format. it should be like "{ "name" : "abc"}". please provide the same and test it.

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan How does ^ this explain the exception not getting *caught* and thrown out?

Comment: from the above code snippet there are two times `gson.fromJson("test", Fulfillment.class)` and IllegalStateException is due to first time. so the next one within the try is not invoked.

Comment: Please attach the stack trace that you get with the exception -- that will allow us to  see where it is being thrown (probably at line 2 as @RajkumarNatarajan suggests)

Comment: Where is line 164 in your code?

Comment: @tgdavies Line 164 is the line with gson.fromJson()

Comment: Exactly how do you know it isn't being caught? What do you expect to happen if it is caught? What happens instead?

Comment: Maybe you log configuration is not corrent so you dont see output of log.error("Error happening for client PO: " + clientPO, e);  Did you try to run this example in debugger?

Comment: @tgdavies It isn't being caught because it's being thrown. If it was being caught, I wouldn't be seeing the error happening ~1m times in StackDriver. If it's caught, I'm returning null, so the Guicy task that expects this method to return something just stops running after a null check. Instead of catching the error and returning null, the error actually gets thrown, and the Guicy task keeps refiring and repeating this cycle.

Comment: @Арсен Мирзаян The log is not the issue here. The issue is that NO error whatsoever should be getting thrown by the try block, because I have the line catch (Exception e) ....

Comment: Are you really sure that you are running the latest version of your code? Try it in a debugger, or add a log statement before the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: What does the gson.toJson call return?

Comment: Figured it out guys!

Comment: What was the error @P_equals_NP_2021 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. So turns out @Slf4j's log.error() call shows the exception as an error in Google StackDriver, hence telling me I've been getting millions of errors.

Answer (score 4):

You need to catch JsonSyntaxException like this

**For Kotlin**

> catch(e: JsonSyntaxException){
>
> ```
>  //show toast/snackabar/log here
> ```
>
> }

**For Java**

> catch(JsonSyntaxException e){
>
> ```
>  //show toast/snackabar/log here
> ```
>
> }

Earlier I was also catching java.lang.IllegalStateException but it didn't worked.
Seems the root exception here is JsonSyntaxException and thus, we need to catch this one.
It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

when(...).thenReturn(null) points that you use some mocking library (jMock, Mockery or simular). And you define that if fromJson("test", Fulfillment.class) is called mock should return null. Actual method fromJson is not invoked as you already defined result. 
If you want expection to be thrown, then remove line

```
when(gson.fromJson("test", Fulfillment.class)).thenReturn(null);
```

Comment: I actually wasn't able to reproduce the error in tests, so editted the question to have my failing code, rather than the unit test. The error is still happening.